# Why do the colours on this picture look nice?

Tags: color

I don't know anything about photography so forgive my question.

I was looking at this particular video clip on youtube and I just really liked the colours. Can anyone explain why? What's this effect called?

[image]

Comment: "Nice" is so subjective. To me, this looks hideously dull and washed out.

Comment: @FreeMan fair point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's this effect called?

[Color grading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_grading).

It's a term that includes making adjustments to not only hues and tints of colors, but to overall contrast, brightness, black point, white point, etc. as well.

With still images we used to call this process *color correction*. This implied that the goal was to reproduce, as accurately as possible, the colors observed in the scene by the photographer when the scene was photographed. But now, as often as not, the goal is to create a sort of alternate reality that leaves the image with some sort of stylized look. So the term color grading, which has been around in cinematic circles much longer than in the stills imaging sector, is now more and more used in reference to still imaging as well.

In the case of your example screen grab, contrast has been reduced by raising the black point and lowering the white point. The blacks aren't totally dark and the whites aren't totally bright. Some of the individual color bands also seem to have been pulled in opposite directions. Green has been shifted toward yellow, while aqua has been shifted the other way, towards blue.

Answer (score 3):

The image has no "effects". It has a reduced contrast.

Look at the blackest zone of a shadow... it is not black, it is grayish(1). And the lightest zone of the image is not white, it is also grayish (2).

There is another spike in the histogram, but that is the white of the background.

[image]

Normally you see more contrasted images, where the blacks are more black and the light zones lighter.

[image]

There are two reasons for the look. The image could have been a high dynamic range image. The camera can capture more differences in lightness between the shadow and the light of the sky. Modern cameras are more capable of this and the resulting image is grayish-er because it still has room for more.

The second reason is using a "cinematic" color grading which has these duller colors, less contrasted to make the images more "real" with a raw look.